# How to properly monitor the actual number of database connections from WebSphere 6.1?

Tags: websphere, connection-pooling, jmx, websphere-6

I need to monitor the actual number of connections from Websphere to the database. I've tried to do this in three different ways, but each way gives me a different outcome.
I'm working on Webpshere 6.1 with several nodes, each containing three servers. All servers are in the same cluster.

1. **Tivoli Performance Viewer.** In TPV, I can choose a particular server, then Performance Modules, JDBC Connection Pools, Oracle RAC JDBC Provider. From there I can see the total number of connections created, closed and the size of the connection pool. Fine, but this gives me an average value of 1 or 2 for PoolSize.
2. **Accessing MBeans using Jolokia.**
   I've deployed Jolokia application on the cluster so it should be distributed to every server. The application works, however when I do the "list" command, which should list all possible MBeans on Websphere, it gives me hundreds of them, but all of them are related to the first instance on the node. For example, when accessing Jolokia using 192.168.1.1/jolokia/list, it gives a list of MBeans, all related to the first instance (server1) configured on 192.168.1.1. Shouldn't it show MBeans related to all three servers on that node? Nevertheles, the value from there is also 1 or 2 as in TPV.
3. **Using netstat in Linux shell.**
   Another problem here. When listing the established connections to the particular database using netstat, it shows about 30 connections from each server process, which gives around 90 connections to the database from the node. I don't understand where that connections came from.

Which information is most relevant here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

From the [JDBC PMI counters](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rprf_datacounter2.html) `PoolSize` gives you current size of the pool on the given server, but not necessary active connections (but they will be opened from the database and netstat point of view). You can use `PoolSize - FreePoolSize` to get number of currently used connections.

To get overall number of connections you would have to monitor each server, or use the database monitoring tools.

You can also install and use [PerfSevlet](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_devprfservlet.html) to get these counters in the XML form.

Comment: the problem is that the PoolSize on each server has a value of 1 or 2 for each server. On the other hand, the same server process on Linux has about 30 established connections to the database (netstat used).

Comment: @Rubid The only reason for that might be incorrect database connection usage by application. So application is not utilizing datasources from the server, but manually creating direct connections to the database. In that case unfortunately you would have to rely on database monitoring tools, not WebSphere.